# bitrix / убрать дубли из фильтра

Tags: битрикс

Имею простой фильтр. Однако в блоке присутствуют элементы с одинаковыми наименованиями. Что дописать, чтобы отказаться от дублей по наименованию ? Мне достаточно первого элемента массива, остальные не показывать.

```
$arFields = array();
                $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>'15','PROPERTY_157'=>$arElement[ID], "ACTIVE"=>'Y');
                $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array('NAME'=>'asc'), $arFilter, false, false, array('ID','NAME'));
                while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    echo ''.$arFields[NAME].'&nbsp';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте два аргумента в GetNextElement

```
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement(true,false)){ 
// Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$elemIdArr = []; // массив с id элементов
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();           
    //проверка на дубли
    if(in_array($arFields["ID"], $elemIdArr)) continue; else $elemIdArr[] = $arFields["ID"];
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]